# I can't upgrade my linux kernel, mkinitrd not found?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

```
$ sudo apt install -f linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (4.4.0-38.57) ...
Running `depmod`.
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/mkinitrd: not found
Failed to create initrd image.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$apt-cache policy linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic:
Installed: 4.4.0-38.57
Candidate: 4.4.0-38.57
Version table:
 *** 4.4.0-38.57 500
500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The only files in `/etc/depmod.d/ubuntu.conf`:

```
search updates ubuntu built-in
```

As for the deb checks, `sudo debsums -cs` used to find a million missing files but I reinstalled all the packages. Here are the remaining errors:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/config.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/cupshelpers.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/installdriver.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/openprinting.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/ppds.cpython-35.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/xmldriverprefs.cpython-35.pyc
```

Here are all the errors with initram, because mkinit came up with nothing:

I did `sudo apt -f install` command had the same result as before. I'm not even sure if there's a log file

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic`?

Comment: Ok I added it, do let me know?

Comment: Hm… this is all quite weird. There is no `/usr/sbin/mkinitrd` in Ubuntu. What do you have in `/etc/depmod.d/`? And could you please perform a [package system sanity check](/a/57728/175814)?

Comment: Done check it out

Comment: Thanks. The complete output of `debsums -cs` might be helpful and is the best clue I have at the moment. You can already search for `mkinitrd` within it specifically.

Comment: Ok, it's huge so I've added grep linux and initram. Let me know if that's not enough. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: You have deleted a bunch of files it seems, so you will need to reinstall the relevant packages.

Comment: If the listing is too long you can uploaded it to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and include a link to it in the question. Anyway, could you please reinstall all these packages to fix missing and corrupted files [as described in this answer](/a/392326/175814)? You can reuse the saved output of `debsums -c` if you still have it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok except for those python errors I mentioned, debsums officially isn't finding any non-matching packages anymore, but it's still not updating. Do I need to fix those python packages? Also, I have no problem running update-initramfs -u -k all. Please let me know if you have any further ideas? I just don't get what could be calling mkinitrd. I use arch on another subvolume but not sure how this happened.

Comment: If you can give any further things I could try, that would be great!

Comment: Any ideas how I can find out what script is calling initrd and where? Maybe that can solve my problem.